# create new opportunity record for that contact

Tags: trigger

Create a trigger to Process Stagings and insert Opportunity
 Object:  staging__c 
Fields:

1. Individual_or_Organization__c (Text)
2. Organization_Name__c
3. First_Name__c
4. Last_Name__c
5. Postal_Code__c
6. Date_Recieved__c (Date)
7. Amount__c (Currency)
8. Error_Message__c (Long Text)
9. Description__c

Requirement:

Case1.  If  Individual_or_Organization__c==I  , 
●   Search for existing contact with matching FirstName , LastName and Postal Code. If contact not found then create new contact.

●   If staging record contains value in Organization_Name__c  and Postal_Code__c Fields then search for account with matching name and postal code. If account found then link contact record with this account.

●   Create new opportunity record for that contact

Case2. If  Individual_or_Organization__c==O
●   Search for existing Account  with matching  Orgganization_Name__c and Postal Code. If Account not found then create new account.

●   If staging record contains value in Last_Name__c and Postal_Code__c  Fields then search for contact with matching firstname,lastname  and postal code. If contact found then link contact record with the  account.

●   Create Opportunity record for account

Field Mapping for Opportunity:

> OpportunityName = Account Name or Contact Name+CloseDate
>
> ColseDate = Date_Recieved__c
>
> Amount = Amount__C
>
> Description=Description__c
>
> ---

```
trigger ProcessStaging on staging__c (after insert) {

    ProcessStagingOpportunity.handleafterInsert(trigger.new);

}
```

---

```
public class ProcessStagingOpportunity{
    public static void handleafterInsert(List<staging__c> listStage){   
        Map<String ,Id> contactMap = new Map<String ,Id>();
        Map<String ,Id> accountMap = new Map<String ,Id>();
        List<Contact> insertContact = new List<Contact>();
        List<Contact> finalcontact = new List<Contact>();
        Map<String,Account> conMapTest = new Map<String,Account>([select Id,Name,BillingPostalCode from account LIMIT 10]);
        system.debug('first'+conMapTest);
        Map<Id,Account> conMap = new Map<Id,Account>([select Id,Name,BillingPostalCode from account LIMIT 10]);
        system.debug('mappp' +conMap);
        List<Contact> conlist = [select Id,firstname,lastname,OtherPostalCode from contact ];
        List<Account> acclist = [select Id,Name,BillingPostalCode from account ];
        system.debug('aaaa' +conlist);
        for(Contact con : conlist) {
            contactMap.put(con.firstname +'_'+ con.lastname + '_' +con.OtherPostalCode,con.id );

        }
        for(Account ac : acclist) {
            accountMap.put(ac.Name,ac.id );

        }

        for(staging__c st :listStage) {
            Id accs;
            if(st.Individual_or_Organization_c__c =='I'){

                if(!contactMap.containsKey(st.First_Name_c__c+ '_' +st.Last_Name_c__c +'_' +st.Postal_Code_c__c)) {


                    Contact cc =new Contact();
                    cc.firstname=st.First_Name_c__c;
                    cc.lastname=st.Last_Name_c__c ;
                    cc.OtherPostalCode =st.Postal_Code_c__c;
                    insertContact.add(cc);
                    system.debug(insertContact +'listtttt');
                    Opportunity op= new Opportunity();
                    op.name= cc.firstname;
                    op.ContactId=cc.id;
                    if(st.Organization_Name_c__c !='' && st.Postal_Code_c__c !='') {

                        if(accountMap.containsKey(st.Organization_Name_c__c)) {
                            system.debug('hellohey');
                            //accs = new account();
                            system.debug('aaa' +accountMap.get(st.Organization_Name_c__c));
                            accs = accountMap.get(st.Organization_Name_c__c);
                            system.debug('######'+''+accs);

                                cc.accountId = accs;


                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        insert insertContact;
    }
}
```

Variable does not exist: ContactId on line 38
I have to create new opportunity record for that contact

Comment: Opportunity don't have Contact lookup. Check the API name.

Comment: You should check the [OpportunityContactRole](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitycontactrole.htm) documentation. This is how you link an opportunity to a contact.

Comment: I am confused what should I use in place of ContactId. I have to create new opportunity record for that contact.